# Django on Pycharm: ImproperlyConfigured with DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-views, pycharm, django-settings

I am trying to use Pycharm Community Edition to improve on my code in my Django application, but I cannot run all of my Django code that I'd like. I keep getting this traceback...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:/Users/Jaysp_000/firstSite/PROJECTone/blog_static/views.py", line 1, in <module>
   from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
 File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 3, in <module>
from django.middleware.csrf import CsrfViewMiddleware, get_token
 File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\middleware\csrf.py", line 14, in <module>
from django.utils.cache import patch_vary_headers
 File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\utils\cache.py", line 26, in <module>
from django.core.cache import caches
 File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\cache\__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
if DEFAULT_CACHE_ALIAS not in settings.CACHES:
 File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 48, in __getattr__
self._setup(name)
 File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 42, in _setup
% (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting CACHES, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

This error seems to involve the `django.views.decortors.csrf.csrf_exempt` that I imported to my views.py file. I've tried other files, and they have given me no issues. There is something in particular about this import, but I don't know what.

```
from django.views.decortors.csrf import csrf_exempt

@csrf_exempt
def handle_hook(request):
    from django.http import HttpResponse
    from django.core.management import call_command
    result = call_command('update_blog', verbosity = 0)
    return HttpResponse(result)
```

The same kind of issue shows up when I am trying to run the code on the python shell (I use 3.4) and when I `import django.http.request as request`. I type in `handle_hook(request)`, and I get the same kind of error.

Im being told that I must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings, but I haven't a clue on how to do that. I've looked around and I am not certain if those methods specifically speak to my issue. Any clues?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Go to the Run Menu, select Edit Configurations..., then select the run configuration for you tests.

Select the environment variables button.  You'll see one existing variable, which is PYTHONUNBUFFERED 
Under that add (for example) DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=mysitename.settings

[image]